# Authenticating to SurveyMonkey API in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, surveymonkey

I'm attempting to authenticate to SurveyMonkey API. I have the redirect URL set to http://localhost and I'm running this application locally.

Here are the authentication instructions:
https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs#oauth-2-0-flow

I think I've completed the first part correctly, but I'm not sure what needs to happen next:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var builder = new UriBuilder("https://api.surveymonkey.com/oauth/authorize");
        builder.Port = -1;
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
        query["response_type"] = "code";
        query["redirect_uri"] = "http://localhost/";
        query["client_id"] = "XX";
        builder.Query = query.ToString();
        string url = builder.ToString();

        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);


    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you just put your api key out to the public?

Comment: You must change the code with the token, step 3 of your link

Comment: So do I take the response and do the same process again, basically? @Max

Comment: On your redirect_uri the authorization server send the code, you parse the url, get the access code, then call the authorization server with the code for the token. I think you must read about oAuth2 protocol.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, after you load the page `/oauth/authorize` in the browser, when the user clicks "Authorize" on that page, SurveyMonkey will redirect to your `redirect_uri`. In this case, your browser will move to:

```
http://localhost/?code=<mycode>
```

You probably want to add an endpoint on your server call `/surveymonkey/oauth` or something.

You'll want to grab that code from your server and then do a POST to `https://api.surveymonkey.com/oauth/token` with the body as a url encoded form post, looks like this:

```
client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&code=AUTH_CODE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&grant_type=authorization_code
```

If you're not building a public app for other users to use (just for yourself) there is an oauth token provided in the settings section of the developer portal to use at https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say "the user clicks 'Authorize' on that page," do you mean that every end user of my application will have to authorize?